# How to re-start a python script without killing other python processes

Tags: bash, python, programming

I develop an app called [Unity Mail](https://launchpad.net/unity-mail). A quicklist option «Edit accounts data» needs to restart it.

#### File */usr/bin/unity-mail*:

```
#!/bin/sh
python /usr/share/unity-mail/unity-mail.py $@
```

#### File */usr/share/unity-mail/unity-mail.py*:

> (Main python script)

When I try to terminate the script using `killall unity-mail`, the unity-mail process is killed, but python process is still running, so unity-mail is active.

I tried to put the python script directly to /usr/bin/unity-mail, but calling `killall unity-mail` in that case says «unity-mail: no process found».

#### The question:

How should I modify /usr/bin/unity-mail so that killing it will kill python also?

Comment: Could you clarify what a quicklist option is?

Answer (score 2):

No need to change your files.

Just type `pkill -f unity-mail` to kill both bash script and python process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PID, from top on Terminal you can see the PIDs, anyways, this is better from programming side, but thats another story